# Always getting "POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/product net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (BAD REQUEST)" when doing a POST with fetch to Flask REST API

Tags: javascript, flask, fetch, http-post

I'm always getting the error `"POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/product net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (BAD REQUEST)"` when I try to do a POST request with fetch in JavaScript to a Flask REST API (when I try to do with GET it works).

This is the code I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/product', {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: 'Product 5',
            description: 'This is product one',
            price: 350.80,
            qty: 100
        })
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import os

# Init app
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# Database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False # this line prevents a warning to show up in the console
# Init db
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# Init ma
ma = Marshmallow(app)

# Product Class/Model
class Product(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
  description = db.Column(db.String(200))
  price = db.Column(db.Float)
  qty = db.Column(db.Integer) #quantity

  def __init__(self, name, description, price, qty):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.price = price
    self.qty = qty

# Product Schema
class ProductSchema(ma.Schema):
  class Meta: # fields that we are allow to show 
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'qty')

# Init schema
product_schema = ProductSchema() # strict=True prevents a warning to show up in the console
products_schema = ProductSchema(many=True)

# Create a Product
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def add_product():
  name = request.json['name']
  description = request.json['description']
  price = request.json['price']
  qty = request.json['qty']

  new_product = Product(name, description, price, qty)

  db.session.add(new_product)
  db.session.commit()

  return product_schema.jsonify(new_product)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def get():
  return jsonify({'msg': 'Hello World'})

# Run Server
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm think it's a problem with the JavaScript code, because I tried to make a POST with Postman Desktop Application and it worked:

[Postman App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YYEG.png)

Comment: You are limiting your request by using `mode: no-cors`, maybe its causing conflict.

Comment: @alphα If I remove that line it's shows me a new error: https://imgur.com/0Beo62J

Comment: Thats strange, because you have `@cross_origin()`, try enabling CORS for all routes: `CORS(app)`
Here is more info: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#simple-usage

Comment: @alphα it's done at the line 9 of the .py file, that solved the GET problem I had before, but I don't understand why in for the POST request doesn't work :/

Comment: I will try to run it locally to see where is the problem at, i think its the backend.

Comment: `from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import os

# Init app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

# Create a Product
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin() # Route specific CORS via decorator
def add_product():
  return '{"msg": "Perfect"}'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def get():
  return jsonify({'msg': 'Hello World'})

# Run Server
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
`

Here is a simplification of your server, it worked for me, no errors.

Comment: What i meant is that, my browser receives the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and there is no error. I used route specific CORS, nore info here: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#route-specific-cors-via-decorator

By the way, how your server is managing GET requests? It does not make sense, its only set to POST request. I tried but i get error `405 Method Not Allowed`